# Overload Eigen::MatrixBase<T>

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have a function for which I have several templated overloads. I which to add an Eigen overload to it. I want to be general such as to be able to accept any Eigen matrix. Therefore I use `Eigen::MatrixBase<T>`. The problem kicks in with the overload, where the compiler fails to recognise the closest match with `Eigen::MatrixBase<T>`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

template <class T>
void foo(const Eigen::MatrixBase<T> &data)
{
  std::cout << "Eigen" << std::endl;
}

// ... several other overloads

template <class T>
void foo(const T &data)
{
  std::cout << "other" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  Eigen::VectorXd a(2);

  a(0) = 0.;
  a(1) = 1.;

  foo(a);
}
```

Whereby the output is `other`. How can I make the Eigen overload such that it is the closest match for any Eigen matrix?

Comment: `const T &data` produces almost exact match (modulo constness and valueness), presumably you want to disable this overload with a SFINAE check

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki In overload resolution, binding `const T&` to `T` is considered an exact match.

Comment: @Brian still better than derived to base conversion

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks. Just to clarify I should disallow Eigen objects from `const T &`? How do I do that? Why does this not happen for an `std::vector<T>` overload?

Comment: @TomdeGeus because a function accepting `std::vector<T>` produces equally good match but this one is more specialized that the one accepting `const T&`. the first condition does not hold for `MatrixBase`, which requires derived to base conversion, so partial ordering is not considered at all

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I see. What is the best strategy to disable Eigen objects from the SFINAE check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Eigen::VectorXd` is a typedef for `Eigen::Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1>`. Going foward, `Eigen::MatrixBase<T>` is a base class for `Eigen::Matrix<T>`. In overload resolution, reference binding of an instance of `Eigen::VectorXd` to the deduced `const Eigen::VectorXd&` parameter has the Exact Match rank which wins with Derived-to-Base conversion (required by `void foo(const Eigen::MatrixBase<T>&`).

As a solution, you can disable the function template producing the exact match with a SFINAE check, so that it is excluded from the set of candidates, leaving the one requiring the derived-to-base conversion the only viable function.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    std::true_type test(const volatile Eigen::MatrixBase<T>&);
    std::false_type test(...);
}

template <typename T>
using is_eigen_matrix = decltype(detail::test(std::declval<T&>()));

template <class T>
void foo(const Eigen::MatrixBase<T>& data)
{
}

template <class T>
auto foo(const T& data)
    -> typename std::enable_if<not is_eigen_matrix<T>::value>::type
{
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b71620706db76df)

Comment: Similar check can be implemented in C++03